# Final Field Semantics

Tags: java, jvm

17.5. [final Field Semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5)

Example 17.5-1. final Fields In The Java Memory Model

```
class FinalFieldExample { 
    final int x;
    int y; 
    static FinalFieldExample f;

    public FinalFieldExample() {
        x = 3; 
        y = 4; 
    } 

    static void writer() {
        f = new FinalFieldExample();
    } 

    static void reader() {
        if (f != null) {
            int i = f.x;  // guaranteed to see 3  
            int j = f.y;  // could see 0
        } 
    } 
}
```

I have been troubled by this problem for several days.

Could anyone **directly** answer me why it the f.y could be see 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If thread A assigns `y`:

```
Thread A:
   writer();
```

And thread B reads `y`:

```
Thread B
   reader();
```

Then `y` has been read without any synchronization and therefore might not see the value assigned.  It's a simple application of Java's synchronization requirement.  If you still don't understand it please clarify in your question.

To put this another way, if `y` were declared as `volatile` then it would be guaranteed to be seen.

```
class FinalFieldExample { 
    final int x;
    volatile int y;
```

Then:

```
static void reader() {
    if (f != null) {
        int i = f.x;  // guaranteed to see 3  
        int j = f.y;  // guaranteed to see 4
```

Comment: Well, clarify my question that the variable isn't null means it has been assignment, so the new object should be constructed and the field should be initialized,right?But why the f.y could be see the default value?

Comment: Because it is unsynchronized.  An unsynchronized write might not be seen by a read in another thread.  That's what that entire chapter 17 is talking about, the need for synchronization.

Comment: To put it another way, if `y` were declared as `volatile` then it would be guaranteed to be seen.

Comment: You mean that It it because the write `f.y=4` might not be seen by the other thread?

Comment: Correct.  The Java memory model guarantees that writes are always visible to the same thread that wrote it.  Thread A will always see `y` as 4, no matter what.

Comment: So , the `final` keyword gurantee the visiable of field like `volatile`?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of the section "Final Field Semantics".  `final` has synchronization semantics similar to `volatile`.  Note it's not exactly the same: `final` is not transitive with other reads/writes, and `final` works for all threads (`volatile` only works for the two threads that write/read the `volatile` field).

Comment: Part of that spec for the section Final Field Semantics: *"the invoked constructor sets a final field, the freeze for the final field takes place at the end of the invoked constructor."* then *"...will always see the correctly constructed version of that object's final fields. "*  So it's called a "freeze-action" and works just a bit differently than *synchronizes-with*, but the broad results are the same.  @梁雨生

Comment: Got it, let me have a look and thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is no [*happens-before*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) relationship between the write operation `[this.]y=4` and the read operation `f.y`. The assignment `y=4` *happens-before* the constructor finishes, and the constructor finishes before the assignment to the static field, but since both threads are directly accessing a static field and do not have a direct joint sequencing relationship, there is no *formal guarantee* that the write to the non-final field `y` is visible in the reading thread. The JLS *does* make a *specific* promise about final fields; in essence, there is a *happens-before* rule that isn't being expressed explicitly (and probably should).

Any mechanism for creating a *happens-before* relationship would solve this theoretical problem, including making *either* `y` or `f` `volatile`.

(Note that I very seriously doubt that any implementation has ever existed that would resequence such that the assignment to `f` was executed before the constructor finished, but the JLS is making the point that there is no *guarantee* except in the case of final fields that this won't happen.)